# SSRS Report Builder - VIewing PDF via Action within report

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

In an existing SSRS 2008 r2 report, I want to be able to display a PDF document when the user clicks on a link.

My problem is how do I point to a file that is on my workstation and how do I point to a file that is on a server (i do have the UNC path)?

I have tried the following expression options like the following:

1 ="file:\lt-28561\c$\Users\satya\Desktop\Test\03015581.pdf"
2 =”Open PDF File#C$\Users\satya\Desktop\Test\03015581.pdf”
3 ="\ServerIPAddress\Pres"& Fields!WO.Value & ".pdf" &"&rs:Command=GetResourceContents"

None of the above options work. Could you tell me how to access the location of the Help.pdf file so that the SSRS report will know where the PDF document is located

Comment: Anyone of you could help me in achieving this please?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but if you have the .pdf on your report server, you should be able to set the `action` on a textbox to `Go to report` and select that .pdf from the report server.  EDIT: Actually, if you have it on the report server, you can set the action property to `go to URL` and basically post the link from the .pdf on your report server, however it may require authentication doing that way.

Comment: Thanks for getting back Steve. 
Well yes it works OK if the .pdf's are on the http://OurDomain/Reports/ location, however if we go with this route, we are having issues in copying the .pdf automatically onto the web path location, hence we are looking for a solution of the UNC path side.